# java Collections synchronizedMap not working

Tags: java

Below code gives when I run the below code multiple time `ConcurrentModificationException`.
When I use non `concurrentHashMap` it is working fine.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<String, String> stringSyncedMap = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<String, String>());

        CollectionJob collectionJob1 = new CollectionJob(stringSyncedMap, "read");
        CollectionJob collectionJob2 = new CollectionJob(stringSyncedMap, "write");

        Thread thread1 = new Thread(collectionJob1, "T1");
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(collectionJob2, "T2");

        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();
    }

}

public class CollectionJob implements Runnable {

    private Map<String, String> stringCollection;
    private String operation;

    public CollectionJob(Map<String, String> stringCollection, String operation) {

        this.stringCollection = stringCollection;
        this.operation = operation;
    }

    public void run() {

        if (operation.equals("read"))
            readFromCollection();
        else
            writeToCollection();

        System.out.println("done");

    }

    public void writeToCollection() {
        for (int i = 10; i < 20; i++) {
            stringCollection.put("String " + i, "String"+i);

    }

    public void readFromCollection() {
        for (String str : stringCollection.keySet()) 
            System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

What I am missing.

Comment: Note that `ConcurrentHashMap` explicitly protects against `ConcurrentModificationException` (returning a "view" of the collection) unlike most of the other collections.

Comment: You are not using a `ConcurrentHashMap` in your code. That's a different thing than what `Collections.synchronizedMap` returns.

Comment: @Kayaman That duplicate isn't really relevant. Ths question is about the difference between ConcurrentHashMap and Collections.synchronizedMap

Comment: @PaulBoddington I'd say it's definitely relevant, even though it's not the exact duplicate. His title also indicates that he probably doesn't know what `ConcurrentModificationException` is. You could vote to reopen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike `ConcurrentHashMap`, you need to explicitly synchronize over your `Map` when initialized through the `Collections.synchronizedMap` idiom, e.g. using the `synchronized` keyword.

From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedMap%28java.util.Map%29):

> It is imperative that the user manually synchronize on the returned map when iterating over any of its collection views: [...]